# serial port file descriptor: when is FD_ISSET set?

Tags: c, file-descriptor

When I put data to a serial port (in my case it is a virtual `/dev/pts/21`) : when can I read the `FD_ISSET` flag `== True`?

Is it when the data is presented to the port?

OR

Is there any control character necessary? (for example: `0x0D` carriage return)

Comment: The [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) function returns with a descriptor set if a call to `read` (for the read set) or `write` (for the write set) will not block. That's all. What that means depends on operating system, which you don't tell us.

Comment: A serial port/pseudo terminal/etc.  under *nix has a line discipline and all sorts of other historical accidents, features, misfeatures and surprises. (e.g. it usually defaults to Canonical Input, in which your program might not receive anything until the other end sends a newline). You can get some basic info at http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x56.html

Comment: Thanks both - didn't receive a notification from the forum what caused the delay. 
@Someprogrammerdude Ubuntu 14
So it obviosly depends on the chosen input concept which is I assume canonical Input (by line)